# cl option unable to build the file which is presented at the relative UNC location

Tags: windows, visual-studio, makefile, gnu-make, unc

I'm trying to build the file which is presented at the UNC path. Here I'm providing simple example to get more clarity.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "additionApi.hpp"

int main(){

    int a=10, b=20;
    std::cout<<"Addition:"<<addNumbers(a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

**tmpOperation\additionApi.hpp**

```
int addNumbers(int a, int b);
```

**tmpOperation\additionApi.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
int addNumbers(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

**tmpOperation\Makefile**

```
tmpOperationDir = \\unc\path\location\tmpOperation
%.obj:%.cpp
    cl /TP /Od /Oy- -Zi /EHsc -I"." -I"$(tmpOperationDir)" /c $< /Fo$@

../math_exe:additionApi.obj ../main.obj
    link /OUT:../math.exe  additionApi.obj ../main.obj

all:../math_exe
```

In the above file structure, I'm using make command from the tmpOperaion directory. main.cpp is presented at outside of the tmpOperaion directory. So I'm accessing main.cpp using the relative path as ../main.cpp in Makefile. But it is unable to build the main file and giving the following error.

```
gmake: *** No rule to make target `../main.obj', needed by `../math_exe'.  Stop.
```

So finally, below are my straightforward questions:

1. Can we build a file(main.cpp in the given example) relatively from the UNC path ?
2. Does UNC paths are supports file inclusion in make file like -I"$(UNC_PATH)" ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Which version of Make are you using? And are you sure that the path `../main.cpp` is correct? That is, that the file `main.cpp` is in the directory above the directory where you are executing Make? (Note that the directory where you execute Make is not necessarily where the makefile resides.)

Comment: the path is correct only. Are you using Microsoft visual studio 2017 ? Still you are unable to reproduce, can you please send me the steps that you are followed. And my straight forward question is does UNC paths are supports file inclusion in make file like  -I"$(UNC_PATH)" ?  and can we build a file(main.cpp in the given example) relatively from the UNC path ?

Comment: Your two "straight forward" questions are different from your implied original question ("what is wrong here?") and are unclear. Please ask *one* question.

Comment: @Beta basically I have doubt regarding using UNC paths in my Makefile. Question 1 is related to my original post only. Can you please clarify both if you know ?? (else) lets talk about the question 1 only.

Comment: For the question1, instead of using relative path, if we use absolute path then it solves the issue.

Comment: For the question 2 , UNC path directories are included properly in Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

We may have to do this in several steps.

First, change this:

```
%.obj:%.cpp
```

to this:

```
../%.obj:%.cpp
```

And try `make ../main.o` and tell me the result.